# How to combine two openapi/swagger schemas into one single schema

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I have two schemas in openapi file:

```
SchemaA:
  type: object
  properties:
    property_a1: 
      type: string
    property_a2: 
      type: string

SchemaB:
  type: object
  properties:
    property_b1: 
      type: string
    property_b2: 
      type: string
```

I want the resultant schema to be:

```
ResultantSchema:
  type: object
  properties:
    property_a1: 
      type: string
    property_a2: 
      type: string
    property_b1: 
      type: string
    property_b2: 
      type: string
```

I have tried using allOf operator to combine like this:

```
ResultantSchema:
  type: object
  properties:
    - $ref: '#/SchemaA'
    - $ref: '#/SchemaB'
```

But this produces result as a schema with two objects inside:

```
WrongResultantSchema:
 - type: object
    properties:
     property_a1: 
      type: string
     property_a2: 
      type: string
 - type: object
    properties:
     property_b1: 
       type: string
     property_b2: 
       type: string
```

Which is wrong... Is there any way to achieve the Resultant Schema with a single object instead of two nested objects?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to combine multiple schemas in OpenAPI 3.0:

```yaml
ResultantSchema:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaA'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaB'
```

In OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`):

```yaml
ResultantSchema:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/SchemaA'
    - $ref: '#/definitions/SchemaB'
```

Comment: No, this does not works, it still shows two objects under one schema.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what's wrong?

Comment: @RahulMidha  This worked for me.  Make sure 'allOf:' is on the same level as 'properties:'